# Book from Induction phenomena with lots of exercises and solutions in English

Tags: resource-recommendations, education, electromagnetic-induction

I know the theory of electromagnetics in BSC-MSC level,
e.g.: as like in these physics books:
Alvin Hudson Rex Nelson UNIVERSITY PHYSICS
David J. Griffiths INTRODUCTION TO ELECTRODYNAMICS

But now I would like to find an electromagnetic text book
for electrical engineers in English.
The following books in German language would be good for me but in English.
Adalbert Prechtl: Vorlesungen über die Grundlagen der Elektrotechnik
Band1 , Band 2
In this book I like the more hundred exercises with solutions, and
many examples of applied practice.
I am particularly interested for induction phenomena like in Chapter 20 in Band2.

Can anyone suggest in English like this Prechtl's book emphasize Chapter 20?

Comment: (1) https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc1.31822011445921&view=1up&seq=9 and (2) https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015002017682&view=1up&seq=7